# How should I parse a very large number with scientific notation (+301)?

Tags: c#, parsing, console

I am trying to parse the answer for `Math.Pow(2,1000)` but I only end up with the same answer `1.07150860718627E+301`. I already tried using `BigInteger`, `decimal.Parse` and `double.TryParse`. I want it to be stored in an array without decimals

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by "trying to parse the answer"? `Math.Pow(2, 1000)` will return a `double` - there's nothing to parse. The value you're getting is the closest `double` to the theoretically "correct" value. If you want a *precise* integer value, you should use `BigInteger` and just multiply by 2 a thousand times.

Comment: my bad, I already edited the question

Comment: "I want it to be stored in an array without decimals" - what does that mean? serious question: I cannot parse that in a way that adds context for the question

Comment: @Marc If I'm not misunderstanding, OP doesn't want `150` as `1.5E+2`. Instead they want `[1, 5, 0]`. I think.

Comment: CodeRed - if @John is right about that, that's... quite odd - please clarify!

Comment: @MarcGravell yea, John is correct

Comment: @CodeRed fair enough; that's pretty easy, then... but I have no idea why you wouldn't just store it as a `BigInteger`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

digits as an `int[]`:

```cs
var value = BigInteger.Pow(2, 1000); // note: BigInteger.One << 1000 may be faster?
string s = value.ToString();
int[] digits = new int[s.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
    digits[i] = s[i] - '0';
```

Or if you're after the digit sum (comments):

```cs
var value = BigInteger.Pow(2, 1000); // note: BigInteger.One << 1000 may be faster?
string s = value.ToString();
int sum = 0;
foreach (char c in s) sum += c - '0';
```

(note that this only handles positive values; for negative values, you'd need to special-case the first character)

But to emphasize: it would seem more *natural* to just keep the value as a `BigInteger` throughout.

Comment: So, `1.07150860718627E+301` is `10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376`?

Comment: @CodeRed ish; 1.07150860718627E+301 is an *approximation* of that, where most of the 302 digits are zeros; 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376 is the exact value - but yes, x.yEz means (x.y)*(10^z), i.e. "imagine x.y but with the decimal point shifted z-1 digits to the right"

Comment: Thanks. Btw, I needed it in an array so I can total all digits in that exact value.

Comment: @CodeRed k; if you're after the digit sum, you don't need the `int[]` - you can work from the `string`; I'll edit the answer

Comment: Yea, I actually just deleted my comment after I realized that thing

Comment: @CodeRed the string is character data; we want numbers; conveniently, the numbers 0-10 are sequential in the ASCII/unicode tables and start with zero, so if we subtract the **character** zero from any **character** of an ASCII digit, we get the **numerical** digit. Or as an example, the **character** `'7'` is ASCII 55, the **character** `'0'` is ASCII 48; `'7'-'0'` = 55-48 = 7

Answer (score 0):

A **Single line solution** would be:

```
int[] digitsArray = BigInteger.Pow (2, 1000).ToString ().Select (d => d - '0').ToArray ();
```